Convert strange Datetime format
In one of my MySQL 5.7 tables, I have column that has a strange datetime format.  It looks like this:
2024-08-09 20:57:31.4477

I am trying to use this query to convert it to a date format m/d/Y.  Here is what I am currently trying:
update table set `column1` = 
CASE column1
    WHEN '' THEN NULL 
    ELSE date_format(str_to_date(`column1`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s %P'), '%m/%d/%Y')
END;

But I am getting the below error:
Incorrect datetime value: '2024-08-09 20:57:31.4477' for function str_to_date

When trying to compare the datetime column, I also used this format:  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s %p' but I am getting the same error.
What is the format I should be using in str_to_date for the datetime above?
I tried to use these formats:
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%P'
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%p'
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%s'

Still getting the same error.

Where is the dot in your format?

@trincot - updated my question.  I included the dot, but still getting the same error.

Where did you get %P from? I don't see it in the docs. There is however %f for microseconds. It's all in the docs.

there is no %P. There exists a %p but that is for matching AM/PM which doesn't exist in your date string.

@trincot - the %f appears to have worked.  I wasn't 100% sure what those extra numbers were.  If you post an answer, I will accept it.

There is a date/datetime datatype for storing date/datetime data.

The final four digits in that example date string "2024-08-09 20:57:31.4477" are the fractional part of the seconds, i.e. there are 32.4477 seconds mentioned, or otherwise put 32 seconds and 447700 microseconds. The correct way to indicate you've a fractional part for the seconds component in your input string, is %f.
Note there is no %P specifier, and the %p specifier concerns AM/PM. See SQL 5.7 docs on date and time functions.
So use '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f' as format string for the str_to_date function.

I faced the same issues before due to the bit length of the datetime field. When designing the table, you should minimize the size of the datetime field value.
If you don't like to change the design of the table you could try this one.
UPDATE table_name 
SET column1 = 
    CASE 
        WHEN column1 = '' THEN NULL 
        ELSE DATE_FORMAT(
            STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column1, '.', 1), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), 
            '%m/%d/%Y'
        )
    END;


I accepted the answer from trincot, however I am curious about minimizing the size of the datetime field.  How did your initially look?  If I wanted to just get the date and not the time, could I set the table field to a date and just keep the length at 10 (yyyy-mm-dd)?

Use datetime datatype. Don't store as strings.

If you only need to store the date (without any time component), using the DATE data type is appropriate. This data type takes up 3 bytes of storage and stores values in the format YYYY-MM-DD (with a length of 10 characters when represented as a string).

I'll try to import the datetime into a DATE data type next time, but I could've sworn I got a "data too long" error last time.  I can't recall of the top.  Does that sound something that should happen with the DATE data type?
